# What is Enumerator object? (Created with String#gsub)

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I have an attributes array as follows,

```
attributes = ["test, 2011", "photo", "198.1 x 198.1 cm", "Photo: Manu PK Full Screen"]
```

When i do this,

```
artist = attributes[-1].gsub("Photo:")
p artist
```

i get the following output in terminal

```
#<Enumerator: "Photo: Manu PK Full Screen":gsub("Photo:")>
```

Wondering why am I getting an enumerator object as output? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Please note that instead of `attributes[-1].gsub("Photo:", ""), I am doing attributes[-1].gsub("Photo:")` So would like to know why enumerator object has returned here( I was expecting an error message) and what is going on.?

Ruby  - 1.9.2

Rails - 3.0.7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An [`Enumerator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html) object provides some methods common to enumerations -- `next`, `each`, `each_with_index`, `rewind`, etc.

You're getting the `Enumerator` object here because [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) is extremely flexible:

```
gsub(pattern, replacement) → new_str
gsub(pattern, hash) → new_str
gsub(pattern) {|match| block } → new_str
gsub(pattern) → enumerator
```

In the first three cases, the substitution can take place immediately, and return a new string. But, if you don't give a replacement string, a replacement hash, or a block for replacements, you get back the `Enumerator` object that lets you get to the matched pieces of the string to work with later:

```
irb(main):022:0> s="one two three four one"
=> "one two three four one"
irb(main):023:0> enum = s.gsub("one")
=> #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x7f39a4754ab0>
irb(main):024:0> enum.each_with_index {|e, i| puts "#{i}: #{e}"}
0: one
1: one
=> " two three four "
irb(main):025:0>
```

Answer (score 5):

When neither a block nor a second argument is supplied, gsub returns an enumerator. Look [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) for more info.

To remove it, you need a second parameter.

```
attributes[-1].gsub("Photo:", "")
```

Or

```
attributes[-1].delete("Photo:")
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Note with `#delete` it will delete every character in the given string, not the word. e.g. `"Photo of an otter".delete("Photo:") # => " f a er"`